# Simple combinatorial logic assignment fails

Tags: verilog, hdl, test-bench, verilator

I wrote a simple `dummy` module in Verilog. It basically copies the value from inputs to the outputs.

```
module dummy (
    input clk,
    input [7:0] vector1 [3:0],
    output reg [7:0] vector2 [3:0]
);

always @* begin
    for (integer i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1) begin
        vector2[i] = vector1[i];
    end
end

endmodule
```

Then I had the testbench file:

```
module tb0;

    // Inputs
    reg clk;
    reg [7:0] data_in1 [3:0];

    wire [7:0] result [3:0];

    // Instantiate the module under test
    dummy uut (
        .clk(clk),
        .vector1(data_in1),
        .vector2(result)
    );

    // Clock generation
    always begin
        #5 clk = ~clk;
    end

    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        data_in1[0] = 8'h00;
        data_in1[1] = 8'h00;
        data_in1[2] = 8'h00;
        data_in1[3] = 8'h00;

        #10 data_in1[0] = 8'h0f;
        #10 data_in1[1] = 8'h04;
        #10 data_in1[2] = 8'h0e;
        #10 data_in1[3] = 8'h0a;

        $monitor("Time = %d: data_in1[1] = %d, data_out[1] = %d", $time, data_in1[1], result[1]); 

        #20 $finish;
    end
    endmodule
```

If I understand correctly, say the value `data_out[1]` should be zero initially, and then change to `8'h04` after 20 time units. But, when I run my Verilog testbench, I get `data_out[1]` fixed to zero. Why is that?

**Updated**: I have updated my script to the following:

```
module tb0;
    // Inputs
    reg clk;
    reg [7:0] data_in1 [3:0];

    // Output
    wire [7:0] result [3:0];

    // Instantiate the module under test
    dummy uut (
        .clk(clk),
        .vector1(data_in1),
        .vector2(result)
    );

    // Clock generation
    always begin
        #5 clk = ~clk; // Toggle clock every 5 ns
    end

    initial begin
        $monitor("Time = %d: data_in1[1] = %d, data_out[1] = %d", $time, data_in1[1], result[1]); 
        
        clk = 0;
        data_in1[0] = 8'h00;
        data_in1[1] = 8'h00;
        data_in1[2] = 8'h00;
        data_in1[3] = 8'h00;

        #11 data_in1[0] = 8'h0f;
        #11 data_in1[1] = 8'h04;
        #11 data_in1[2] = 8'h0e;
        #11 data_in1[3] = 8'h0a;
        
        #20 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

And I still get the following as output:

```
Time =                    0: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                    5: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                    5: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   10: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   10: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   11: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   11: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   15: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   15: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   20: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   20: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   22: data_in1[1] =   4, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   22: data_in1[1] =   4, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   25: data_in1[1] =   4, data_out[1] =   0
...
```

I am using Verilator.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the simulation, I see the following output:

```
Time =                   40: data_in1[1] =   4, data_out[1] =   4
```

I get a different output from you (`data_out[1]` is 4, not 0).  This may indicate a bug in your simulator tool (Verilator).

Notice that the time is 40 because you call `$monitor` after 4 delays of 10 time units (`#10`).

It is more common to call `$monitor` at time 0, like this:

```
initial begin
    $monitor("Time = %d: data_in1[1] = %d, data_out[1] = %d", $time, data_in1[1], result[1]); 
    clk = 0;
    data_in1[0] = 8'h00;
    data_in1[1] = 8'h00;
    data_in1[2] = 8'h00;
    data_in1[3] = 8'h00;

    #10 data_in1[0] = 8'h0f;
    #10 data_in1[1] = 8'h04;
    #10 data_in1[2] = 8'h0e;
    #10 data_in1[3] = 8'h0a;
    #20 $finish;
end
```

This is the output I get, which may be more of what you were expecting:

```
Time =                    0: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   20: data_in1[1] =   4, data_out[1] =   4
```

Another approach is to call `$display` instead of `$monitor`, and call it at a time when the signals are stable (not at the edges):

```
always @(posedge clk) $display("Time = %d: data_in1[1] = %d, data_out[1] = %d", $time, data_in1[1], result[1]);
```

Output:

```
Time =                    5: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   15: data_in1[1] =   0, data_out[1] =   0
Time =                   25: data_in1[1] =   4, data_out[1] =   4
Time =                   35: data_in1[1] =   4, data_out[1] =   4
Time =                   45: data_in1[1] =   4, data_out[1] =   4
Time =                   55: data_in1[1] =   4, data_out[1] =   4
```

Run it on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/va5a).  You can see the waveforms as well.

I was going to recommend you submit a bug report, but I see [you have already done so](https://github.com/verilator/verilator/issues/4868).  It looks like Verilator has now been fixed to support your syntax.